# Printing product of odd numbers 1 -15

Tags: c++

I need to write a program that will print out the product of all the odd integers between 1 and 15. HOwever no matter what i try it won't work, and will just print product. Did i mess up the if statement? Here is my code:

```
//Sophia Ali
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    int i;
    int product;

    for ( i = 1; i <=15; i+=2)
    {
        if(i%2!=0)
            product = product * i;
        else
            continue;

    }
    cout << "\n product: " << product;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That if condition will always be true. Turn up your warning level for the problem.

Comment: You miss to initialize product=1. There's no need for if-statement (else or continue), as i+=2 will take care of i being odd.

Comment: Your `product` is not initialized.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you do not initialize `product` which means you end up with undefined behaviour. You might want to initialize it to `1`:

```
int product = 1;
```

In addition, the `if` condition in your loop will always be true since you are increasing `i` by 2 at each iteration anyway, so it has no purpose:

```
for ( i = 1; i <=15; i+=2)
{
    product = product * i;
}
```

Comment: I had it at i++ but I thought maybe that was the problem. So I should just keep it at i++?

Comment: They'll both have the same result. I would stick with `i += 2`.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does'nt define anything for you. so when you declare `int product;` in the 2nd line of the main function, you should instead use `int product = 1;`. Otherwise when you use `product = product * i` in the for loop, you are saying to multiply a non-existant number by i, which is impossable.